# Getting hold of tag content in XQuery 3.0 (exist-db)

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I am using the following XQuery code for selecting all .html documents within a collection
of exist-db. The script should create an XML document (serialized as JSON) with document URI and title (which is stored as the first H1 element).
However the the  element remains empty. Why?

```
xquery version "3.0";
declare option exist:serialize "method=json media-type=text/javascript";

<result> {
    let $data-collection := '/db/output'
    for $doc in collection($data-collection)
    where contains(base-uri($doc), '.html')
    return 
        <item>
            <url>{base-uri($doc)}</url>
            <title>{$doc/h1/text()}</title>
        </item>
}
</result>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have simplified your lookup for HTML documents, but I think your `h1` element is not the root of the document, instead I have assumed that it might be anywhere in the document so have used the `descendant-or-self` axis, e.g. `//` and as your HTML may be in a namespace I have used the `*:` prefix to indicate any namespace.

```
xquery version "3.0";

declare option exist:serialize "method=json media-type=text/javascript";

<result> {
    let $data-collection := '/db/output'
    for $doc in collection($data-collection)[ends-with(base-uri(.), '.html')]
    return 
        <item>
            <url>{base-uri($doc)}</url>
            <title>{$doc//*:h1/text()}</title>
        </item>
}
</result>
```